# Delete invalid row(duplicate) from table which has the valid entry

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, duplicates, sql-delete

I need delete the duplicate entries which has the status of inactive in `empl_status` value . For each employee there should only one active `emp_id` other rows need to be deleted.

```
DELETE
FROM EMPLOYEE_MAT
WHERE EMP_ID IN
  (SELECT MAX(EM.EMP_ID),
    (SELECT ASSOCIATE_ID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE USER_ID =UT.EMP_GUID
    ) AS user_name,
    EM.EMP_STATUS
  FROM EMPLOYEE_MAT EM
  JOIN EMP_TRANS_TABLE ET
  ON EM.UT_ID = ET.UT_ID
  WHERE EM.EMP_STATUS NOT LIKE 'Active'
  GROUP BY EM.EMP_ID ,
    ET.EMP_GUID,
    EM.EMP_STATUS
  HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
  ORDER BY EM.EMP_ID,
    user_name
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't that just `delete from your_table where act_status = 'Inactive'`? That's what the screenshot suggests.

Comment: @Littlefoot not really. OP wants to delete Inactive employees when there are duplicates by Id.

Comment: Please post data as plain text not images, and include the expected results, and what the problem is with your current statement. It seems like you want to delete all inactive rows where there is a matching active one - so if there is *only* an inactive record that is kept - right? But then why isn't the fifth row in your example deleted too?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the following methods which will delete all Active/Inactive record except one Active record.

If no Active record found for the user with multiple Inactive records, 
then 1st query will retain one Inactive record and delete all other duplicates. While in same situation 2nd query will not delete a single record.

If there are two active records found then both the query will delete one and retain one Active records.

From your question, Both of the below queries will delete 1st and 5th records.

Use queries according to your requirements.

**1. Using analytical function:**

```
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE_MAT
WHERE
    ( ROWID,
      EMP_ID ) IN (
        SELECT
            ROWID,
            EMP_ID
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    ROWID,
                    EMP_ID,
                    ACT_STATUS,
                    USER_NAME,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                        PARTITION BY EMP_ID, USER_NAME
                        ORDER BY
                            UPPER(ACT_STATUS)
                    ) RN
                FROM
                    EMPLOYEE_MAT EM
            )
        WHERE
            RN > 1
    );
```

**2. Using EXISTS:**

```
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE_MAT EM
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            EMPLOYEE_MAT EMIN
        WHERE
            EM.EMP_ID = EMIN.EMP_ID
            AND EM.USER_NAME = EMIN.USER_NAME
            AND EMIN.STATUS = 'Active'
            AND EMIN.ROWID <> EM.ROWID
    );
```

Note: Add the necessary conditions according to your requirements.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DELETE employee_mat a
WHERE  act_status = 'Inactive'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM   employee_mat b
            WHERE  a.emp_id = b.emp_id
            AND    a.rowid <> b.rowid
            AND    b.act_status = 'Active')
```